# A lot of errors 400 access.log with Nginx and loadbalancer

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, web-server, load-balancing, log-files

Hy,

I have juste install nginx for my website, and everything is working well and very fast :)

But i have this kind of error in my access log :

IP - - [30/Dec/2011:11:06:00 +0000] - "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

IP - - [30/Dec/2011:11:06:10 +0000] - "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

IP - - [30/Dec/2011:11:06:20 +0000] - "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

IP - - [30/Dec/2011:11:06:30 +0000] - "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

This error is caused by my loadbalancer, which is one of amazon ec2 LB. And i haven't find any solution to resolve this problem.

Due to this error my log is growing very fast. What can I do for exlude it from my log ?

Thanks for your help.

And happy new year (with anticipation !!!).

Comment: You should solve the problem rather than treating the symptoms. What's your 'ping path' for your ELB's HTTP health check? Make sure that it begins with a slash, .e.g. "/index.html", otherwise it may not be considered a valid HTTP request and hence the 400 errors.

Comment: Ok my ping path is a html file and the path is starting with a slash. like /toto.html (and there is just some text in this file) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hmm, I would be tempted to do a tcpdump of your http traffic to see what could be causing the errors; something unusual in the http headers perhaps. Also, could be related to large cookies: http://blog.craz8.com/articles/2009/06/17/nginx-400-bad-request-errors-due-to-cookies-and-what-to-do-about-them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, i have try to play with this instructions large_client_header_buffers and it didn't change anything.
Do you think i can exlude from the log just my htlm health check file ?
thanks for you help

Comment: Upgrade nginx to a newer version. see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111260/configure-nginx-to-not-log-elb-secondary-healthcheck/18112078?noredirect=1#comment26531256_18112078

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not stopped these entries by adjusting your LB's polling of your server, you can use Apache's SetEnvIf to do conditional logging.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#conditional

I have some clients who use this for certain image directories. They have graphic rich sites and images are >95% of the hits. The logs were GB's per day before excluding the images.

In your case, you could probably exclude by IP address.

**EDIT:**
Sorry mis-read.  Nginx has a log not found option:

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#log_not_found

This turns off 404 in the error log.  You can then use a location directive:

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif)$ 
{ root /var/www/html; 
*access_log off;* 
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am working with nginx....

Comment: Sorry misread.  Thought you were using Nginx to LB to Apache systems.

Comment: thanks for your edit, I am trying to use this option. thanks again, i think it is the solution for my case !

Comment: This is not a solution, it only removes 404 errors, not 400 errors.